# Are relics bought for rubies scaled to the current level?

Tags: clicker-heroes

In Clicker Heroes, you can use rubies to do a number of different things, one of which is buy three random relics.

Is the quality of the relics dependent on the current level or are they as good (or bad) as ones you would normally get when ascending?

**Edit:** As in, is it better to purchase the relics later in a run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The position you are at in your current run does not determine the level of relics that you will get. You will just get the next three that you normally would've gotten otherwise (if you played through three ascensions).

Similarly they will scale in the same way which is as a percentage (2/3) of your highest level ever reached.

If you wish for the highest level relics when you buy it then you should buy them after you have set your highest level: Go for a long run, getting to a higher level than you have previously, and then purchase the relics.

Comment: Good, useful information. Do you have any source?

Comment: @Svj0hn [Here](http://clickerheroes.wikia.com/wiki/Relics#Relic_Ooze) for the wiki on relics with the formula for how them scaling as a percentage of HZE, also in the comments someone has asked the same question as you and the response agrees exactly with what I learnt from testing the game to see how it works. There's no way to ever change what you will get, relics or gilded or anything, it will always be the same. Probably due to the same random seed being used.

Comment: Great. Perhaps you could update your answer to include the source and additional details?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and it *seems* to scale with the level. The rarity isn't scaled but the level of the items. I had an Level 5 relic as I was at Level 120 and a Level 10 as an Item dropped at Level 290. The Items I purchased at Level 380 are Level 13, which seems to be related.

Comment: All three were level 13?

Comment: No not all 3. 1 Level 13, 2 Level 12. But anyway, as I mentioned it *seems* to scale. I haven't enough rubies to test it twice. :-D